# Identify next value greater then multiply by column D of same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: excel screen shot]

What I need to do is enter a number in `G2` then look for the = or next value > `G2` in column `B`.  I then want to multiply `G2` by value in Column `D` on the same row we identified above.  I would like the output to be in `H2`.

In this example I have 60 in `G2` so it would identify `B3` because `B2` is < `G2` and `B3` is next increment higher.  It would then multiply `G2 * D3` the formula / answer would be in `H2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to my answer is that you have to sort your col B items in descending order. If that won't work, I can keep looking, but in the meantime.

1. Sort A2:E4 by col B descending order (larger numbers on top)
2. In H2 enter the following formula:

`=G2*INDEX(D2:D4,MATCH(G2,B2:B4, -1))`

**--OPTION 2--**

If you are able to reference the amount in G2 somewhere in column B then there is another option available.

In B1 (I know you have something there, but these purposes I replaced it) put following formula

```
=G2
```

In H2 put the following formula

```
=G15*INDEX(D2:D4,MATCH(SMALL(B1:B4,RANK(G15,B1:B4,1)+1),B2:B4,0))
```

**--OPTION 3 - This is the one!--**

I was curious so I digged a bit more, and this one gets what you want.

Short story, is that it looks for the smallest number that is greater than the value indicated, then returns the value in that row but column D and multiplies by G2. Only this time there is no changes to your data.

Enter this formula in H2, but press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of just Enter.

```
=G2*INDEX(D2:D4,MATCH(MIN(IF(B2:B4>G2,B2:B4)),B2:B4,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data in `B1:B4` are ordered, use this one:

```
=INDEX(D1:D4,IFERROR(MATCH(G2,B1:B4,0),1+MATCH(G2,B1:B4,1)))*G2
```